# Get event information using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to track button clicks a user performs on a page/view. I am trying to get the element idwhich was clicked.

Is there a way to do this without having to tie a function or directive to each element?

Comment: Would [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2422-capturing-document-click-events-with-angularjs.htm) be what you're looking for? Maybe not the directive proposed by Ben, but what you find in the first comment by Fritz.

Comment: @Jonathan. I have tried this already, but what I am looking for is the element name of the click. I will update the question.

Comment: Well, this is a very interesting problem. I don't know if angular is actually capable of solving it. I agree with callmekatootie that it does appear to be a problem for JQuery... If, however, I find a solution in angular, I'll definitely share it!  I'm currently working on an website analytic tool that would benefit from the solution to this question!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the id?  When you add a click handler to the document you can just get the id by doing `event.target.id`.  See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6QKUivv4O2GE2N08f9Tv?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `ng-controller` and `ng-click`

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyController" ng-click="go($event)">
  <div id="box1">
    <div id="box2">
      <div id="box3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$scope.go = function(e) {
  var clickedElement = e.target;
  console.log(clickedElement);
  console.log(clickedElement.id);
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/1O6pCVrvgu7Bl8b6TlPF?p=preview

### Directive:

HTML:

```
<body my-directive>
  <div id="box1">
    <div id="box2">
      <div id="box3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {

  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      element.bind('click', function (e) {
        var clickedElement = e.target;
        console.log(clickedElement);
        console.log(clickedElement.id);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/eevnMFu2YBj3QqRraeZh?p=preview